# cannot resolve symbol import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkinAndroid;

Tags: java, javafx, java-6, jfoenix

I trying to run the demo app based on javaFX and jfoenix UI library on intellij, I have the jdk1.8.0_131 and jre1.8.0_131 version but I unnable to run, what Im doing wrong? 
this import throws me error:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkinAndroid;
```

I already set the JAVA_HOME and gradle environment variables and I already build the demo with gradlew

I need another version of jdk and jre for run this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the root folder of the project
open the "build.gradle" (not the other build.gradle that are inside of folders)
comment out the code: 
mave{ url 'http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/maven2',

it should now look like this:

```
//maven { url 'http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/'}
```

then run `gradlew build`

Comment: I only have this line in my root build.gradle:

`maven { url 'http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.com/sevntu.checkstyle/maven2' }`

Is this line?

Comment: Yes. Be careful to only add // after the first bracket, abd before the url to comment out the whole url.